# Функция urlencode в cURL POST

Tags: curl, php

Изначально файлы заливались в папку сервера и не было печали, но встал вопрос о перенесении всех картинок на статик...
Зашифрованная в base64 картинка передаётся методом post с помощью curl на статик сервер, где уже расшифровывается и сохраняется в файл. В теории хорошо, но на практике после 2 часов непонимания, что же такое случается с картинкой, я понял, что base64 за время отправки ломается (думаю, из-за `urlencode`). Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать, чтобы передать его, не сломав? Может быть, какой-нибудь шифр поставить, чтобы всё было в 1 строку из букв и  цифр?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте перед раскодировкой из Base64 заменить все пробелы на +

```
base64_decode(str_replace(' ', '+', $_POST['image']));
```